# LINQ: join based on table name

Tags: c#, linq

I have a log table with int the following format. It has logs belonging to multiple tables. My requirement is to get the records from this table joining with only one table(in my case ClientPrograms).

ApplicationLogs:

```
Table               PrimaryKey  IssueDetails
ClientPrograms      123         Sample Issue
ClientAffiliations  456         Sample Issue
```

Here is the table I need to join with the above table on PrimaryKey=>ClientProgramId only if the 
table name is "ClientPrograms"

ClientPrograms:

```
ClientProgramId SubTopicId      DateCreated 
123             12              10-05-2019
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
Table               PrimaryKey  SubTopicId  IssueDetails
ClientPrograms      123         12          Sample Issue
ClientAffiliations  456                     Sample Issue
```

As you can see the output has SubTopicId only when the table name is ClientPrograms. For all the other tables it can be null/blank.

I don't know the correct LINQ for this. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

This is what I have tried:

```
//Get all the records
var allRecords = (from p in ApplicationLogs
select new
{
  //columns here
}).ToList();

//Get the records with table "clientprograms"
var filteredRecords = (from p in ApplicationLogs
join pe in db.ClientPrograms on p.PrimaryKey  equals pe.ClientProgramId
where p.Table.ToLower() == "clientprograms"
select new
{
  //columns here
}).ToList();

//Get the records without table "clientprograms"
var remainingRecords = (from p in ApplicationLogs
where p.Table.ToLower() != "clientprograms"
select new
{
  //columns here
}).ToList();
```

Here I am thinking of joining "filteredRecords" and "remainingRecords". But is this the right approach? Anything available in LINQ for this particular 
scenario?

Comment: Define at least some classes representing your tables, to let others form a query. In this condition the question isn't even C# related.

Comment: Google left joins. Also, can you please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

var result = ApplicationLogs.Where(a=>a.Table==“ClientPrograms”).Select(//select as per your requirement) should work as well.

Comment: That won't give the null `SubTopicId` column and doesn't have a join to select that column from..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var joinedRecords = (from al in db.ApplicationLogs
                    join cp in db.ClientPrograms on al.PrimaryKey equals cp.ClientProgramId into cp1
                    select new 
                        {Table = al.Table,
                        PrimaryKey = al.PrimaryKey,
                        SubTopicID = cp1.SubTopicID,
                        IssueDetails = al.IssueDetails
                        }
                    ).ToList();
```

This assumes you data source is `db`. The field SubTopicID in your results list will be `null` if there is no matching record in `ClientPrograms`

You shouldn't be joining on a table name but on the primary key as that is the unique identifier of the record.